# POST vars from flash to php file_put_contents filename

Tags: php, string, actionscript-3, flash, variables

I'm recording webcam data and sending to a .php to be stored and viewed later within the flash. That element is working fine but I need to give the file a unique ID each time it does this based on variables set in flash.

here is the code I'm using to POST the flv as a byteArray:

```
     var url_ref:URLRequest = new URLRequest("save_vid.php");
     url_ref.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
     url_ref.data = _baFlvEncoder.byteArray;//url_data;
     url_ref.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
     urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
     try {
             urlLoader.load( url_ref );
         } catch (e:Error) {
             trace(e);
         }
```

The variables I need to append to the filename set in PHP file:

```
    var currentVideo:String;
    var currentName:String;
```

My PHP file so far:

```
    <?php
    echo 'Data:<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
    file_put_contents("test.flv",$GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ]);

    $sCurrentVideo = $_POST['currentVIdeo'];

    $sCurrentName = $_POST['currentName'];
    ?>++
```

Can anyone here lead me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the "[URLVariables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html)" class.

[Here is a helpful tutorial explaining it's usage.](http://www.creativearmory.com/tutorials/how-to-use-actionscript-3-to-post-to-php-and-retrieve-variables)

Create an instance of it, set the values to match the two variables you want set, also add in the raw video data.

```
// Define the variables to post    
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
urlVars.currentVideo = currentVideo;
urlVars.currentName = currentName;
urlVars.videoData = _baFlvEncoder.byteArray;
```

Then in the `urlReq`, set the data equal to the `urlVars` instance:

```
url_ref.data = urlVars;
```

You will then be able to access these values in the $_POST variable in PHP.

`file_put_contents("test.flv",$_POST[ 'videoData' ]);`

Comment: Rather than adding it to the file name string its saving that var data with the byte array and corrupting the flv. Is there a way to append the vars from the flash to the flv name in the php? In flash I was using 
        `fileRef.save(_baFlvEncoder.byteArray, "perform"+id+"_iGame.flv");`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... You're saying in using URLVariables, it corrupts the flv data?

Comment: I was saying, the php was using all the data set in the urlVars to compile the flv. it was using data set in the currentVideo and currentName var along with the byeArray data to compile the flv. Corrupting the file. What I need to do is instad of using "test.flv" as the file name, i need to use the data from the currentVideo and currentName vars to name the file. Do you know how I would do such a thing?

Comment: Something like:
        `file_put_contents($_POST[ 'videoData' ] + "test.flv");`

Comment: `file_put_contents` takes a string for the title for the first parameter (i.e. $_POST['currentName']) and data of the file itself for the 2nd parameter. It should work with `file_put_contents($_POST['currentName'], $_POST['videoData']);`

Comment: How should I be structuring my php file so that it can see and seperate those vars sent from flash? does it matter if the 
    `dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;` 
?